# PHP convert special characters for database input

Tags: php, special-characters

I have a unit in php which gets tv-guide data from several api's. This data sometimes contains special characters like: `carrière`. I put all the tv-guide data in a database, but the special characters get mangled up and change to a `?`.

I think it is not a database problem, because i have set the database to utf8mb4_unicode and also all tables and col's.

I tried this:

```
iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $input);
```

but that doesnt seem to make any difference..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: I have tryed the options there.. but i have no access to php.ini.. i did set the database settings to utf-8, and also set `$conn->set_charset('utf8');`